# Access docs on Gdrive via Python

Tags: python

I am looking for a way to access an .csv document that I have registered on drive to perform data analysis. The idea would be to have something similar as pandas' read_csv but to access a remote file, not one registered locally. Note that I don't want to access a Google spreadsheet document : it's a .csv document that I have shared on Google drive. Ideally, I'd like to be able to save it on Drive as well.

Thank you for the help,

Best,

Comment: If you have google file stream, then you can simply access your file from its path like normal.

Comment: Hi BenT,

Thanks for helping. Would you mind sharing an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to use [Google's File Stream](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7491144?hl=en&ref_topic=7455083) to do this. What it does is basically mount the drive to your computer so that you can access it from anywhere.

So on my windows computer I can open a terminal and then access anything on my drive. (Or if you have a mac you will find it mounted to /Volumes)

```
>>>ls /mnt/g/
$RECYCLE.BIN  My Drive      Team Drives

>>>ls /mnt/g/My\ Drive/
test.csv
```

Comment: Thanks! It seems that I cannot configure Google's File Stream though... It says I need to use an administrator/Gsuite account...